# Fetch only part of your result set at a time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am fetching a huge result set of about 5 million rows (with 10-15 columns) with my query. There is no ID column and one cannot even be created (not my fault), so I cannot even partition my data on the basis of ID and then load it in parts. What makes it worse is that this is SQL server 2000, so most of the convenient SQL coding features might not even be available for this DB. Is there any way i can do something like -

```
Select top 10000 column_list from myTable
then, select next top 10000 column_list from myTable (ie 10001 to 20000)
and so on...
```

Comment: rownumber is the function you'd want to use, but it's not available prior to 2005.  I don't think there is anything short of very clunky answers to this issue.  An alternative is to create a process (run nightly?) that takes the 5 million rows and writes them to a new table that has an ID column, then report from it instead.

Comment: Have you got a `Date` or `DateTime` column by any chance?

Comment: @Twelfth - I was thinking of that too, ie a staging table. But, its suggested that I avoid that too. Not a final word, but its to be avoided. Bad situation.

Comment: @William - Yes, william I was thinking of that too. But the problem is that most of the rows have been loaded on one date. So, maybe I will have to partition by microseconds or minutes. Not too keen on doing that.

Comment: I recommend challenging the recommendation to use a staging table.  By the way, is this a regular event or a one-off job?

Comment: you are not alone in this struggle anyway...  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6936/Paging-of-Large-Resultsets-in-ASP-NET      Unless there is a 'natural key' in your data set (like a datestamp + username + function + etc...) thestaging table seems the best option (challenge it if you can, I'm just not sure how right now).  Curious who would find a select * of 5 million rows displayed 10k at a time at all useful...an aggregate of those rows would be more beneficial.  Maybe revisit the question of why you are doing this, is there a better solution to provide than a 5million row datadump?

Comment: @DanBracuk - Its a one off job, but it is to be done multiple times. Its like this - load info (store, customer, age, loaves purchased, discounts applied etc) for 5 million loaves of brand X bread sold since 2011, then load 3 million rows for loaves of brand Z bread sold since 2011...etc for 50 brands of bread. After loading is complete, I will only have to load 10K to 20K rows for each brand of bread sold in a week, which is fast and easy. I am not dealing with bread though. But, the example illustrates my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a useful index, you can grab 10000 rows at a time by tracking the value based on the index.

Suppose the useful index is LastName + FirstName

```
Select top 10000 column_list from MyTable 
order by LastName, FirstName
```

Then when you get the next 10000 rows, use the query

```
Select top 10000 column_list from MyTable 
where LastName >= PreviousLastname && FirstName > PreviousFirstname
order by LastName, FirstName
```

Pseudocode above assumes no duplicates on the combination, if you could have duplicates, easiest method is to add another column (even if not indexed), that makes it unique. You would need that 3rd column in the order by clause.

PreviousLastname is the value from the 10,000 record of the previous query.

ADDED

A useful index in this context is any index that high a high cardinality -- mostly distinct values or at most a minimal numbers of non distinct values. An extremely non-useful index would be something like gender (M/F/null)

Since you are using this for data loading, the index selection is not important (ignoring performance considerations) as long as it has a high cardinality. Note that the index and and order by clause must match or you will put a heavy load on your database.

REVISION -- I saw an obvious mistake for the additional data where clause

```
where LastName >= PreviousLastname && FirstName > PreviousFirstname
```

This should have been

```
where (LastName > PreviousLastname) 
   or (LastName = PreviousLastname && FirstName > PreviousFirstname)
```

Comment: Please tell me what is useful index and how do I find out if I have one already.

Comment: Updated answer to explain useful index.